# About maximum function and continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $R>0$, and $P$ metric space. If $f:\bar{B}(\bar{x},R)\times P\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. We define $F:P\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $F(p)=\max_{x\in\bar{B}(\bar{x},R)}f(x,p)$. How I can prove that $F$ is continuous?

Thank.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get you started so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(p_n)_n$ be a sequence in $P$ with $p_n \rightarrow p \in P$.

For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ select $x_n \in \overline{B}(\overline{x}, R)$ with $f(x_n, p_n) = F(p_n)$.

Because $\overline{B}(\overline{x}, R)$ is compact, there is some subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ with $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x$ for some $x \in \overline{B}(\overline{x}, R)$.

Then $F(p) \geq f(x,p) = \lim_k f(x_{n_k}, p_{n_k}) \geq \limsup_k F(p_{n_k})$.

It is easier to show $\liminf_k F(p_{n_k}) \geq F(p)$ (do it!)

In conclusion, we get $F(p) = \lim_k F(p_{n_k})$.

This shows that every sequence $(p_n)_n$ with $p_n \rightarrow p$ has a subsequence $(p_{n_k})_k$ with $F(p_{n_k}) \rightarrow F(p)$. Use this to conclude that $F$ is continuous.